# API Gateway directly connected to SNS with SAM

Tags: aws-sam

I would like to define a cloud formation template by sam. I would like to create an API Gateway method directly connected to SNS authorized by a custom authorizer. Is it possible to accomplish it with SAM?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAM offers easy ways to connect API Gateway and Lambda, but doesn't yet offer easy integration between API Gateway and other services. You could open an issue on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues) to propose this feature, but right now, connecting APIGW to SNS in SAM would require a Lambda function to be between those two services.

Someone recently proposed a similar feature for [APIGW -> DynamoDB](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/857) integration, I think APIGW -> SNS would be a similar feature.